# PassengerSpawnMethod "smart" doesn't reduce memory footprint?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, passenger, phusion

Our Rails 3.2 application (Ruby 2.1.5) sits behind Passenger (4.0.59) and uses the default spawn method, which the Passenger docs stipulate is "smart".

Smart spawning is claimed to shave about 33% off the per-process memory footprint.

I was curious how much benefit we were deriving from using smart spawning so I modified our config to specify "direct" spawning.

However, after switching to "direct" the memory footprint of our processes didn't increase like I expected.  This seems to indicate we aren't actually deriving any benefit from smart spawning.

Any theories about why this would be the case?

Are we *not* in fact using smart spawning despite specifying it in the config file?  Is "top" outpu  (specifically the VIRT and RES columns) not a good way to measure per process memory usage?

Something else entirely?

Answer (score 0):

You need Ruby >= 2.0.0 in order to take advantage of the memory savings, because the Ruby garbage collector is only copy-on-write-friendly starting from 2.0.0.

You should not use "top" to measure memory, because it does not take shared memory into account.

Both of these facts are documented in the Passenger documentation:

- https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/indepth/ruby/spawn_methods/
- https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/admin/nginx/overall_status_report.html#accurately-measuring-memory-usage
- https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/indepth/accurately_measuring_memory_usage.html

Comment: Stated in the question we're using Ruby 2.1.5, so that's not the issue.  I'll re-test using passenger-status to measure memory usage.